# Is sending feedback on SFDC Doc errors/incompleteness worth bothering about?

Tags: documentation

When I discover an error or omission in the SFDC Developer Doc, I go to the section at the bottom of the page:

[image]

and fill out the "yes, except" or "no" feedback form. My belief is that since I rely on the doc, where it is incorrect or missing some clarification, that others should benefit from ever-improving documentation.

My question is: Does anyone ever actually read and act on the doc feedback? Is there a better channel to use?  I can imagine that a tech writer has to reproduce the use case, consult with an engineer, go through approvals/QA and that this might be all too much bother given higher value docs to be produced for new features.

Comment: I've done this a few times but have never received any feedback to the email address I supplied and have never had the willpower to check if a change was made in a later version of the documentation. So I will be interested to see what others have to say here.

Comment: I, too, have never received any feedback to the email address supplied by me on the feedback form. Not even a 'thanks'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These reports go directly to the doc writer team, and by far is the quickest & easiest way to give feedback and get improvements in the doc, and is at least as effective as getting bugs logged in the internal system. [I have access to the internal bug system, but still report doc issues via this form]

Comment: Could you share with the doc team that they would probably get more feedback if they responded to people?

Comment: Yes, will pass this along.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a Principal Technical Writer for salesforce.com, and it's true, we do look at all comments and file bugs on the doc issues that are raised. Technical writers are actually hungry for customer feedback.

Please keep commenting. As others have pointed out, it may take a bit of time to receive a comment, research it, make the change and release it, but there's nothing more important to us than hearing from our customers.

Comment: As Keith mentioned on Simon's answer - more responses to those of us using the form might be helpful. Just a "thanks for the feedback, we've accepted it and it should be making it's way into future docs" or "we're investigating the details with R&D" makes people feel much more involved.

Comment: I too would feel better about the times I have submitted such feedback if I at least got a confirmation it was received and has hit eyeballs somewhere.